# jquery-ui datepicker change z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

The problem is pretty straight forward although I'm having a hard time figuring out just how to solve it.

I'm using a jQuery-ui datepicker along with a custom made "ios style on/off toggle". This toggle uses some absolutely positioned elements which are currently showing up on top of my date picker.

see the ugly circle covering july 6th below...

[image]

the dirty way to do this (at least imo) is to write a style in one of my stylesheets, but I'd much rather use some javascript when the picker launches to get this done.

I've already tried

```
$('.date_field').datepicker(); 
$('.date_field').datepicker("widget").css({"z-index":100});
```

and

```
$('.date_field').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) { 
        inst.dpDiv.css({"z-index":100});
    }
});
```

but it seems the z-index get overwritten each time the datepicker is launched.

any help is appreciated!

Comment: I consider a css !important rule on your page's css much more cleaner than javascript, seeing as z-index *is* a CSS property and is there for styling. If I had to do a JS solution, it'd be appending a `style` tag to the head - not only having it in CSS keeps your JS code shorter and cleaner, but also applies for all instances of datepickers seamlessly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715677/trouble-with-jquery-dialog-and-datepicker-plugins

Comment: @Lance not a dupe because I'm asking how it can be done dynamically without adding a line to the css

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I guess I just dont want to muck up my css with some stupid override for a jquery-ui edge-case. The `style` tag in the head is a little closer to what im looking for but what i really want to do is change the style attribute on the date-picker element.

Comment: I already reserve a space in the bottom of the CSS file only for jQuery UI hacks in every project I start, but yeah, I submitted an answer with a pure jQuery solution explaining why CSS would be a cleaner solution, now you can choose which one to use. `=]`

Comment: Here you have sollution for this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033420/jquery-date-picker-z-index-issue

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Your JS code in the question doesn't work because jQuery resets the `style` attribute of the datepicker widget every time you call it.

An easy way to override its `style`'s `z-index` is with a `!important` CSS rule as already mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715677/trouble-with-jquery-dialog-and-datepicker-plugins). Yet another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8704775/1331430) suggests setting `position: relative;` and `z-index` on the input element itself which will be automatically copied over to the Datepicker widget.

But, as requested, if for whatever reason you really need to set it dynamically, adding more unnecessary code and processing to your page, you can try this:

```
$('.date_field').datepicker({
    //comment the beforeShow handler if you want to see the ugly overlay
    beforeShow: function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ndUN/1/)

​I created a deferred function object to set the `z-index` of the widget, after it gets reset'ed by the jQuery UI, every time you call it. It should suffice your needs.

The CSS hack is far less ugly IMO, I reserve a space in my CSS only for jQuery UI tweaks (that's right above the IE6 tweaks in my pages).

Comment: May I just tell you how much you rock!? Tried a myriad of other things first. Thank you!

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works, however as soon as the datepicker is refreshed (e.g. you change the month) the z-index is set back to default, so I think this answer would need a small adjustment, that is to add the following
onChangeMonthYear: function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);
        }, 0);
    }

Comment: @Gombo I believe it is easier if you use one of the CSS approaches (described above the JS one) as those are far less hackish. `;)`

Comment: At least in FF, the max number is 10 digits long, so nine 9's might be more better-er (though FF is happy to convert to 2147483647 without an error).

Comment: +1 for pointing out to set `z-index` to the input DOM. That was the only thing worked for me: `<input .... style="z-index: 9999;"/>`

Comment: This is a very bad practice.

Answer (score 98):

There is a more elegant way to do it. Add this CSS:

```
.date_field {position: relative; z-index:100;}
```

jQuery will set the calendar's `z-index` to 101 (one more than the corresponding element). The `position` field must be `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`. jQuery searches for the first element's parent, which is absolute/relative/fixed, and takes its' `z-index`

Comment: This is definitely the best solution. +1

Comment: Perfect  but in my case :   .datepicker-dropdown {z-index:999999 !important;}

Comment: Almost perfect, but it does not work if you do not know the maximum value of zindex for which you want the datepicker to impose itself.

Answer (score 21):

You need to use `!important` clause to force the in-line `z-index` value using CSS.

```
.ui-datepicker{z-index: 99 !important};
```

Comment: Sorry doesn't work for me - the z-index is set on the element by jQuery which takes higher priority than the !important

Comment: @DylanHamilton-Foster are you sure? Can you please add some other tag, i.e. BackgroundColor, to see if the style is actually applied?

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me when I was trying to use datepicker in conjunction with a bootstrap modal:

```
$('input[id^="txtDate"]').datepicker();
$('input[id^="txtDate"]').on('focus', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).datepicker('show');
    $(this).datepicker('widget').css('z-index', 1051);
});
```

Of course, change the selector to fit your own need.  I set the "z-index" to 1051 because the z-index for the bootstrap modal was set to 1050.

Answer (score 6):

> The datepicker now sets the popup z-index to one more than its associated field, to keep it in front of that field, even if that field is itself in a popup dialog. By default the z-index is 0, so datepicker ends up with 1. Is there a case where this is not showing the datepicker properly? [JQuery Forum Post](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/z-index-1-datepicker-1-8#14737000000803068)

To get a z-index of 100. You need an input with `z-index:99;` and JQueryUI will update the datepicker to be `z-index:100`

`<input style="z-index:99;">`  or `<input class="high-z-index">` and css  `.high-z-index { z-index: 99; }`

You can also specify the z-index to inherit which should inherit from your dialog box and cause jQueryUI to properly detect the z-index.

`<input style="z-index:inherit;">`  or `<input class="inhert-z-index">` and css  `.inherit-z-index { z-index: inherit; }`

Answer (score 3):

In my case nothing worked.
I needed to add the z-index to the input type that has the datepicker.

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" datatype="date" style="z-index: 10000;" id="txtModalDate">
```

Answer (score 1):

The BEST NATURAL way is to simply put the date-picker element on a "platform" that has a "relative" position and has a higher "z-index" than the element that is showing up above your control...

Comment: Please add meaningful code and describe more your `BEST NATURAL way`

Answer (score 0):

**This is for Bootstrap datetimepicker**

If your datepicker is hiding because of scroll appears in your div use:

```css
overflow-x: visible !important;
overflow-y: visible !important;
```

in css of whole div that contain your datepicker and other item such as

```css
.dialogModel{
    overflow-x: visible !important;
    overflow-y: visible !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      $('#datepickers-container').css('z-index', 999999999);
    };
```