# jQuery datapicker appearing behind twitter bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap v2.3.2 and jQuery [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) v1.10.0,

On a modal I am trying to make use of the datepicker and it is appearing behind the modal on Firefox and IE, on Chrome it seems to be working fine.

This is what it looks like on IE and Firefox

[image]

**My Modal HTML**

```
<div id="editGoals" class="modal hide fade" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</a>

        <h3 style="font-size: 18px;" id="myModalLabel"><img src="assets/img/logo_icon.png">Goal Tracker</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="message2"></div>
        <form action="dashboard-goals-ajax.php" method="post" name="goaldataform" id="goaldataform"
              class="form-horizontal goaldataform">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label goal_label_text"><?php _e('Goal Target'); ?>
                </label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-prepend input-append">
                    <span class="add-on">$</span><input type="text" class="input-medium" name="goal_target" id="goal_target" value="">
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label goal_label_text"><?php _e('How much have you saved towards your goal?'); ?>
                </label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-prepend input-append">
                    <span class="add-on">$</span><input type="text" class="input-medium" name="goal_progress" id="goal_progress" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label goal_label_text"><?php _e('Goal deadline'); ?>
                </label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-prepend input-append">
                        <span class="add-on"></span><input class="input-medium" type="text" id="goalDeadline" name="goalDeadline">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="goal_type" id="goal_type" value=""/>
            <input type="hidden" name="goal_target_submitted">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button data-complete-text="Close" class="dt-btn btn-yellow dt-btn-1 pull-right"
                id="goaldatasubmit" name="goaldatasubmit"><?php _e('Submit'); ?></button>


        <div class="gap-10"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**JS For datepicker**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#goalDeadline").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            minDate: +1
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have gone through almost every solution I could find on net and stackoverflow but nothing seems to work. I will really appreciate any help here.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533161/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-z-index)

Comment: @Matt a billion thanks to you. It worked, would you like to add this as an answer so I can mark it. Once again thanks

Comment: Sure thing. Happy it's fixed for you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533161/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-z-index)** covers the issue.

This is a `z-index` issue. Normally applying a higher `z-index` via CSS would work, however jQuery resets the CSS each time the Datepicker UI is drawn.

The solution re-applies the CSS each time it's drawn by using the `beforeShow` property.

Comment: Plain CSS works fine: `.ui-datepicker { position: relative; z-index: 10000 !important; }`

Comment: @Matt, can you help me with a similar issue that I am facing with the time picker  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51654736/time-picker-going-behind-the-twitter-bootstrap-modal

Answer (score 14):

I faced the same issue, fixed it with;

```
.datepicker{z-index:9999 !important}
```

**Ref**: [github](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/1129)

Answer (score 1):

As @Matt answered, apply `z-index` higher than `modal`’s `z-index`,   suppose `modal` has the below `z-index`:

```
modal.fade {
    z-index: 10000000 !important;
}
```

Then apply z-index more than modal for `datepicker` class:

```
.datepicker {z-index: 20000000 !important}
```