# Time picker going behind the twitter bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap date-time picker in my Java Spring MVC web application to select date and time separately. I have included the CSS and scripts required. 
my HTML code would be as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Start</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <!--Bootstrap Datepicker : Component-->
                <div id="dripCampaignStartDate">
                    <label class="control-label" for="startDate">Start Date</label>
                    <div class="input-group date">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startDate" name="startDate" readonly="readonly">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="swcm-pli-calendar-4"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <!--Bootstrap Timepicker : Component-->
                <label class="control-label" for="startTime">Start Time</label>
                <div class="input-group date" id="dripCampaignStartTime">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startTime" name="startTime" readonly="readonly">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="swcm-pli-clock"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">End</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <!--Bootstrap Datepicker : Component-->
                <div id="dripCampaignEndDate">
                    <label class="control-label" for="endDate">End Date</label>
                    <div class="input-group date">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endDate" name="endDate" readonly="readonly">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="swcm-pli-calendar-4"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <!--Bootstrap Timepicker : Component-->
                <label class="control-label" for="endTime">End Time</label>
                <div class="input-group date" id="dripCampaignEndTime">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endTime" name="endTime" readonly="readonly">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="swcm-pli-clock"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">DNS Time</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <!--Bootstrap Datepicker : Component-->
                <label class="control-label" for="DNSStartTime">From</label>
                <div class="input-group date" id="dripCampaignDNSStartTime">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DNSStartTime" name="DNSStartTime" readonly="readonly">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="swcm-pli-clock"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <!--Bootstrap Datepicker : Component-->
                <label class="control-label" for="DNSEndTime">To</label>
                <div class="input-group date" id="dripCampaignDNSEndTime">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DNSEndTime" name="DNSEndTime" readonly="readonly">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="swcm-pli-clock"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using the following javascript code to initialize the date and time pickers:
//Initializing date time pickers

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
var minDateValue = new Date();
var maxDateValue = new Date();

$('#dripCampaignStartDate .date').datetimepicker({
    format: 'L',
    allowInputToggle: true,
    ignoreReadonly: true,
    useCurrent: false,
    minDate: currentDate,
    defaultDate: currentDate
});

$('#dripCampaignEndDate .date').datetimepicker({
    format: 'L',
    allowInputToggle: true,
    ignoreReadonly: true,
    useCurrent: false,
    minDate: currentDate,
    defaultDate: currentDate
});

$('#dripCampaignEndDate .date').data("DateTimePicker").date(tomorrow);

$("#dripCampaignStartDate .date").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#dripCampaignStartDate .date').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment().millisecond(0).second(0).minute(0).hour(0));
    minDateValue = new Date(e.date);
    minDateValue.setDate(minDateValue.getDate());
    minDateValue.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    $('#dripCampaignEndDate .date').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(minDateValue);
    if($('#dripCampaignEndDate .date').data("DateTimePicker").date() < $('#dripCampaignStartDate .date').data("DateTimePicker").date())
    {
        tomorrow = new Date(minDateValue);
        tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
        $('#dripCampaignEndDate .date').data("DateTimePicker").date(tomorrow);
    }
});

$("#dripCampaignEndDate .date").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    minDateValue.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    $('#dripCampaignEndDate .date').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(minDateValue);
    maxDateValue = new Date(e.date);
    maxDateValue.setDate(maxDateValue.getDate());
    $('#dripCampaignStartDate .date').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(moment().millisecond(0).second(0).minute(0).hour(0));
    maxDateValue.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    $('#dripCampaignStartDate .date').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(maxDateValue);
});

currentDate.setTime(currentDate.getTime() + (60*60*1000));

$('#dripCampaignStartTime, #dripCampaignEndTime, #dripCampaignDNSStartTime, #dripCampaignDNSEndTime').timepicker({
    defaultTime: currentDate
});

$('#start-Time').val($('#dripCampaignStartTime').val());
$('#endTime').val($('#dripCampaignEndTime').val());
$('#DNSStartTime').val($('#dripCampaignDNSStartTime').val());
$('#DNSEndTime').val($('#dripCampaignDNSEndTime').val());

$(document).on( 'change', '#dripCampaignStartTime' ,function (event){
    $('#start-Time').val($('#dripCampaignStartTime').val());
});

$(document).on( 'change', '#dripCampaignEndTime' ,function (event){
    $('#endTime').val($('#dripCampaignEndTime').val());
});

$(document).on( 'change', '#dripCampaignDNSStartTime' ,function (event){
    $('#DNSStartTime').val($('#dripCampaignDNSStartTime').val());
});

$(document).on( 'change', '#dripCampaignDNSEndTime' ,function (event){
    $('#DNSEndTime').val($('#dripCampaignDNSEndTime').val());
});
```

I have no issue with selecting date. The issue happens with the time picker. I found few solutions related to z index, but dint seem to work for me.

Comment: Hi Geo. I've managed to get an example running here: https://codepen.io/Kanx/pen/Yjvymb?editors=1000

It doesn't look as though the issue is arising from the base CSS contained in the respective libraries - are you able to share your custom CSS?

Comment: @Matt, I really appreciate your help, but I might not be able to share my custom css. But I believe there isn't much that my css is doing here. I am able to use the same code and get both the date and time pickers working. But the issue occurs only with modal.

Comment: Ah sorry Geo - I missed the modal part. I've got another [codepen](https://codepen.io/Kanx/pen/Yjvymb?editors=0010) here using a modal which is working. Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @Matt, I am using bootstrap version 3.3.6

Comment: @Matt, I also see that the time picker works fine in your modal. Have you made any changes

Comment: I've just used your HTML and wrapped it in a basic modal - no further changes i'm afraid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177348/discussion-between-geo-thomas-and-matt).

Comment: I got the issue fixed using the following css:                                       .bootstrap-timepicker-widget.dropdown-menu {
    z-index: 1050!important;
}                                                                                                                              got the solution from https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker/issues/326

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found the solution from the following URL:

https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker/issues/326

I added a CSS entry to my stylesheet to set the z-index for the time picker and the issue was solved:

```
 .bootstrap-timepicker-widget.dropdown-menu { z-index: 1050!important; }
```