# date time picker showing behind modal jquery-confirm modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Am not using bootstrap modal but am using

[j confirm modal](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/themes.html)  the problem is am loading a partial page from another page. However when l try using the date time picker it will appear behind the modal
[image]

Most of the solutions online are mostly based on bootstrap modal and have tried using this class also

```
#ui-datepicker-div {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 99999; 
    }
```

but to no avail. 
even this links
[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626526/jquery-datapicker-appearing-behind-twitter-bootstrap-modal)
[another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51654736/time-picker-going-behind-the-twitter-bootstrap-modal)

maybe it is because am using jConfirm js file or what ?

Comment: i would check the z-index value of  j confirm modal, and made z index of  datepicker greater.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the z-index of the dropdown calendar:

```
.datepicker.datepicker-dropdown.dropdown-menu {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 99999; 
}
```

Comment: You need to inspect element and see what is the class of the dropdown calendar.