# bootstrap date picker fails for one user but not others

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a jquery date picker within a modal popup.  I have set a z-index of 999999999 for it to ensure is appears on top of the modal window.  However, for one user the date picker appears behind the modal window.  I have tried clearing the cache and restarting the machine with no luck. It works for all other users as far as I know.  Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks for the help.

Here is some code:
Modal popup

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"
        PopupControlID="pnlTimedActivityAddUpdate"
        TargetControlID="btnDummy"
        CancelControlID="lbCancel"
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
```

Panel within popup

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlTimedActivityAddUpdate" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopupContainer">
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopupBackground"> 
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" CssClass="innerPopupPanel">
                <div class="right">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCancel" runat="server" Text="Close" CssClass="cancel" /> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2><asp:Label ID="lblPopupHeader" runat="server" Text="" /></h2>
                </div>
                <center>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnTimedActivityID" runat="server" />
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">Name:&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="200px" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage="* Required" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">Category:&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCategory" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlCategory" ErrorMessage="* Required" />
                            </td>                        
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" valign="top"><br /></td>
                            <td align="left" valign="top">
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkUseAnticipatedTime" runat="server" Text="Use Anticipated Time" />
                                <div id="divAnticipatedTime" style="display:none">
                                    Minutes:&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtAnticipatedMinutes" runat="server" Width="25px" CssClass="right" Text="0" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    Seconds:&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtAnticipatedSeconds" runat="server" Width="20px" CssClass="right" Text="0" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">Require:&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRequireVolume" runat="server" Text="Volume" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRequireMinutes" runat="server" Text="Minutes" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">Active Dates:&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" width="70px" />&nbsp;to&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" width="70px" />
                                <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" CssClass="ineeddatepopup ineeddatemaxminvalidation" runat="server" width="70px" />&nbsp;to&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" width="70px" />--%>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">Sort Order:&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSortOrder" runat="server" Width="25px" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"><br /></td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" Text="Active" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" valign="top">Description:&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" MaxLength="1000" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="60" Rows="5" />        
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="btnSave_Click" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" onclick="btnCancel_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
                    <br />
                </center>
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Attach a calendar

```
// Attach calendars to start/end date pickers
        $("[id$=txtStartDate]").datepicker({
            minDate: new Date(2014, 1 - 1, 1),
            showButtonPanel: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
```

css for datepicker

```
.ui-datepicker {
    font-size: 85%;
    border: 2px solid maroon !important;
    z-index: 9999999999 !important;
}
```

An example of a working calendar is below.  When the user in question clicks into the date field, the calendar shows behind the modal popup.  This is the only user that has the issue.
[Working datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzQfm.png)

I have looked at other solutions in this forum.  The questions I can't answer is why it works for everyone else *but this one user*.  Machines, browsers, OS's are the same for everyone.

Comment: You should provide a code example or a link to an example of the working code, so that we can see exactly what's happening. Also, an image of what happens and what should happen would be useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery datapicker appearing behind twitter bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626526/jquery-datapicker-appearing-behind-twitter-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: I updated the post with code.