# Datepicker covers the input field within a modal

Tags: jquery, css, django, datepicker, bootstrap-4

The datepicker element is not created correctly within a modal, it covers the input field and I can not visualize the data[image]

html:

```
<div id="datepicker" class="input-append date col-md-12" >
    <input  type="text" class="form-control">
    <span class="add-on">
        <span class="arrow"></span>
        <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

js:

```
<script src="{% static 'assets/plugins/bootstrapv3/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script> 


$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    startDate: "01-01-2015",
    endDate: "01-01-2020",
    todayBtn: "linked",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    container: '#myModal modal-body',
    zIndex: 2048,
});
```

Comment: So what is the question? And what is the #myModal HTML looking like?

Comment: How can I fix this bug ...

Comment: Add the relevant libraries for datepicker.

Comment: what is your HTML? What is the css for the input that is being overlayed? using just the code you gave, with jQueryUI's datepicker, nothing overlays anything. What browsers? What, exactly, is the bug?

Comment: In the third input, the calendar covers the input space.

Comment: yes, yes it does. Which UI library are you using? What CSS?

Comment: I would guess its either YOUR CSS, or the datepicker's CSS -- but its something presentational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for posterity, the datepicker had to be initialized in the input label.

```
<input id="datepicker" type="text" class="form-control">
```

on the other hand I had to implement this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533161/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-z-index/#answer-11534635):