# jQuery datepicker is not working when I include a jQuery slider/banner in PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

My code for jQuery datepicker works fine. But when I include a jQuery slider/banner on same page, the datepicker doesn't work. I think the script tags may conflict with other.

```
Scripts under head tag:
//for datepicker
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

//for slider/banner
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider/themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

html:

Search By Date <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date">
<input type="submit" name="searchbydate" value="Search">

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider(); 
    }); 
</script>

script.js file
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
});
```

PHP code for slider

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"> 

<?php
   include("dbConnect.php");

    $query="select * from event_table where enable_disable='Enable'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            //echo "<img src='images/".$row['image']."' title='".$row['description']."' height='400'>";
            ?>
            <a href="event_details.php?eid=<?php echo $row['event_id']; ?>"><img src="images/<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" title="<?php echo $row['event_name'] ?>" height="450"></a>
            <?php    
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No Events";
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);     
   ?>

    </div> 
   </div>
```

My slider shows 2 extra empty slides at the start and after second slide,it works fine. How to remove extra empty slides?

html code for id="slider"

```
    <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">     
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Connection</title>
</head>
<body>
    </body>
</html>            <a href="event_details.php?eid=9"><img src="images/foot.jpg" title="Indian Super League 4" height="450"></a>
                        <a href="event_details.php?eid=10"><img src="images/volleyball.jpg" title="Pro Volleyball League" height="450"></a>
                        <a href="event_details.php?eid=11"><img src="images/nemo.jpg" title="Nemo Play" height="450"></a>
                        <a href="event_details.php?eid=12"><img src="images/walle.jpg" title="Robot Fight" height="450"></a>
                        <a href="event_details.php?eid=13"><img src="images/badminton.jpg" title="Premier Badminton League" height="450"></a>
                        <a href="event_details.php?eid=18"><img src="images/foot2.jpg" title="English Premier League" height="450"></a>

    </div> 
   </div>
```

Comment: remove one of the jQuerys - for example `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
`

Comment: slider/banner does not show up on removing above jquery library. please help.

Comment: Yes it does. See my answer

Comment: You need to load the proper libraries and of course have the relevant html which you did not post. Look in the console (press F12) for any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove one of the jQuerys - for example `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

I also needed to fix the zindex of the picker [Jquery date picker z-index issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033420/jquery-date-picker-z-index-issue)

and use the CDN for all:

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- for datepicker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- for slider/banner -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-nivoslider/3.2/nivo-slider.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-nivoslider/3.2/jquery.nivo.slider.min.js"></script>

Search By Date <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" style="position: relative; z-index: 100000;" />
<input type="submit" name="searchbydate" value="Search" />
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"> <img src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/nivo-slider/demo/images/toystory.jpg" data-thumb="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/nivo-slider/demo/images/toystory.jpg" alt="" />
  <a href="http://dev7studios.com"><img src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/nivo-slider/demo/images/up.jpg" data-thumb="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/nivo-slider/demo/images/up.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" /></a> <img src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/nivo-slider/demo/images/walle.jpg"
    data-thumb="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/nivo-slider/demo/images/walle.jpg" alt="" data-transition="slideInLeft" /> <img src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/nivo-slider/demo/images/nemo.jpg" data-thumb="demo/images/nemo.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption"
  /> </div>
<div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption"> <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>. </div>
```

Using your html for the slider

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- for datepicker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- for slider/banner -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-nivoslider/3.2/nivo-slider.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-nivoslider/3.2/jquery.nivo.slider.min.js"></script>

Search By Date <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" style="position: relative; z-index: 100000;" />
<input type="submit" name="searchbydate" value="Search" />
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
  <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <a href="event_details.php?eid=9"><img src="https://www.hindustantimes.com/rf/image_size_960x540/HT/p2/2017/11/26/Pictures/hero-isl-m9-atk-v-pune_cb4d0a0a-d2a8-11e7-a40e-766ee48c25bf.jpg" title="Indian Super League 4" height="450"></a>
    <a href="event_details.php?eid=10"><img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/arrest_volleyball_picture_168170.jpg" title="Pro Volleyball League" height="450"></a>
    <a href="event_details.php?eid=11"><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51cdafc4e4b09eb676a64e68/57aa036e20099eb9c945bcae/57aa03705016e1b85aa5821b/1470759793960/nemo11.jpg" title="Nemo Play" height="450"></a>
    <a href="event_details.php?eid=12"><img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/disney/images/2/2b/Wall-E.png/revision/latest?cb=20151002192237" title="Robot Fight" height="450"></a>
    <a href="event_details.php?eid=13"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/31/23/21/badminton-1428047_960_720.jpg" title="Premier Badminton League" height="450"></a>
    <a href="event_details.php?eid=18"><img src="http://www.cyprusupdates.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/FreeGreatPicture.com-19724-football.jpg" title="English Premier League" height="450"></a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yess..it is working. Also the datepicker was hiding inside slider, this problem also got solved by using z-index. Thanks a lot for ur help.

Comment: My slider shows first 2 slides empty with dots. After second slide it works fine. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Make sure the images are loaded. Look in the network tab and console

Comment: All database images loads properly but 2 extra empty slides are shown in the beginning.

Comment: Please post rendered HTML. It is not a php problem

Comment: it only displays database images into slider so I used only php code for that and not html

Comment: You do not understand. Look at my snippet. I went for you to the nivoslider demo site, view-sourced their site to have an example of a nivoslider ***HTML*** I do not care what is GENERATING the HTML, go to your website, view-source, copy enough HTML from the div with id="slider" to show the problem and paste it into a [mcve] in your question

Comment: Why do you have a document inside the div? It is illegal HTML. Get rid of or move    `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Connection</title>
</head>
<body>
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: I updated my code - I added a slider with your HTML. Please VALIDATE your HTML before testing

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are using two jquery libraries and they may have conflicts try removing one of them

I think you should remove :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: slider/banner does not show up on removing above jquery library. please help.